# "Get him off me!" or "Get him off of me!"

Tags: grammar

If I want someone to remove someone from me because he is annoying or harassing me do I need the "of" ? I have heard both and while it may not be required to convey the intended meaning I think it should still be required from a grammaticaal standpoint.

Comment: Both are fine.  When under stress it's common to lose unnecessary prepositions.

Comment: What @Andrew said. Stressed or not, in practice most native speakers would tend to discard at least the second ***f*** (phonetically, ***v***), so it would most likely be enunciated *Get him **offa** me!* (not an uncommon "eye-dialect" orthographic form, as attested by about 150 written instances of [*get him offa*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22get+him+offa%22#tbm=bks&q=%22get+him+offa%22&nfpr=1)).

Answer (score 1):

I think the phrases are practically interchangeable. "Get him off (of) me." It could be 1) rhetorical or 2) literal. "Get him off me" is just less precise and the word 'of' is understood to be there.

1. The boss is always on 'my' case, riding 'me' too hard. This is a request for help deflecting the boss's attention.
2. The man is physically sitting on/lying on 'me'. This is a literal request to have him removed.

Comment: We don't normally say *The boss is on me* for your context #1 (it's usually *He's **on my back*** or ***on my case***), so I don't think OP's text would be at all likely to be used with that sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So you wouldn't say "Get him off (of) me!" if he were *on your back*? Why does it matter whether they're literally or figuratively *on your back*? I've heard the phrase "Get him off my back!" often.

Comment: @userr2684291: The point I'm making is that *Get him off [of] me!* wouldn't be likely in the context of the boss being *figuratively* "on your back/case". Sure - you'll hear *Get him off my back!* often enough, but *Get him off me!* doesn't really work for the figurative context. Thinking about it, one reason you wouldn't often hear *The boss is on me* is probably because it could easily be misinterpreted as *The boss is on **to** me* (he knows about my wrong-doings).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Right. That's how I interpreted it as well.